# Can xcode rotate an UI item without using code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I see a lot of people are using code under `viewDidLoad` to be able to rotate their objects, but isn`t there any way for xcode to do this initally?

If not, what is the most efficient/best way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: by how much do u want to rotate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface Builder has currently no support for setting transform on views (or on their backing layers). You're bound to do it by code.

Comment: Could you help me with how to set it on first UI load?

Comment: Of course: assuming your view is an IBOutlet and is named `myView`, do this in `viewDidLoad`: `myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);` for a 90° rotation, and `3*M_PI_2` for a 270° rotation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Since I am doing this on my IBAction, I need to ask one more:
I added 
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderThrottle;
- (IBAction)sliderThrottle:(id)sender;` and that works, but is it "legal" to have both action and outlet on the same object?

Comment: It's perfectly legal: roughly speaking, an IBOutlet allows your code to talk to your interface ; an IBAction allows your interface to trigger methods in your code. IBActions and IBOutlets serve the same purpose (make two parts of your app talk to each other), but in opposite directions.

Comment: But in this case, it seems your IBAction is mis-named. Usually an action name is something like `- (IBAction)sliderThrottleDidChangeValue:(id)sender`.

Comment: This is good stuff! Thank you! I will try to keep the naming conventioning more correct as well. You`re a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

You can set base view to landscape in the interface builder and build it like that. So everything will be rotated 90 degrees. Also do not forget to edit your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method. In the case that you only want to rotate some objects and not all of them you are going to have to go with the transforms as Cyrille said.